# How to stop current page rendering process while navigating to another one?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vuejs3

I have this Vuejs app with a page that renders a lot of elements, while rendering elements I click on a link to navigate between pages and it's not happening until the current page is rendered completely; How can I stop it from rendering or navigating immediately to the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't, since within a Vue app, you are no doubt using javascript routing rather than a simple `<a href=(some url)...` to navigate between pages. Your click handler is going to be called when the flow of the javascript gets around to it, which will certainly be after rendering. So the only way to get there quicker would be to hard load the new page by using the good old `<a href="new-page-url"...`, aborting the javascript process wherever it is. But you probably don't want to pay that price.